# how to define IP address as a constant variable in C programming?

Tags: c, ip

I need to use IP address of the eth0 interface of a PC (Linux OS - IPv4). How can I define it as a constant variable without knowing the IP address in advance?

Comment: What OS? You'll need to make a system call to look it up if you don't know it *a priori*.

Comment: Language itself has nothing to do with it. You either need a library that would be more or less portable, or simply a system-call.

Comment: This question is very ambiguous. You have not provided sufficient info. What it will be used for? You can store it as `unsigned char[4]` (or 6 in case of IPv6), as a string, in the format XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, as one of the BSD sockets' host struct types (struct inaddr etc.)... !?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021549/get-ip-address-in-c-language -> Similar.

Comment: I think what's more important question is, why do you need it to be const ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have them as pointer to an address buffer you can. Export a pointer to `const` qualified type

```
extern your_address_type const*const addr;
```

You'd have to have your library code see something like

```
static your_address_type my_address;
your_address_type const*const addr = &my_address;
```

Inside your library you can then initialize `my_address` properly, client code only would see `addr` and wouldn't be able to change it.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot.

There are two ways to define a constant quantity in C: the preprocessor (`#define`) and constants (`const something`). Both of these require that the value of the constant be known at compile time¹. So if your aim was to have a way to refer to this IP without having the possibility of overwriting it with another value during program execution, it's simply not doable.