# Easy Method to Verify IP address has been issued

Tags: c++, network-programming, dhcp

I'm writing a C++ program on a linux box (DHCP client) that depends on the connectivity of the network. I need to pragmatically verify that my system has a IP address.  I know this is a general and open ended question, so any quick and dirty solution will work for me, but ideally I would like to check/read a system file to ensure the DHCP client has received an IP address from the DHCP sever.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021549/get-ip-address-in-c-language

Comment: Brendan, I have only conducted research at this point.  Gabriel, I'm familiar with that thread, thx, I hoping that there's a system file that read to get the info I need.

Answer (score 2):

Just try any operation that requires an IP address and that should work if there is one. A DNS lookup comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have a look at the source of say `ifconfig`, since that gets the ip address if one is assigned.  A quick strace suggests that it might be an ioctl such as

```
ioctl(4, SIOCGIFADDR, {ifr_name="eth0", ifr_addr={AF_INET, inet_addr("<my ip>")}})
```

and a grep of /proc/net for my IP address suggests that if you know how to parse `/proc/net/fib_trie` you might be able to get it from there.